# nodejs, mysql-model insert into database

Tags: mysql, node.js

Im trying to post some random test data to my database but it gives me some 404 error..

The form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/arts">
<input type="text" name="test">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

The code to handle the post:

```
  var test = new MyAppModel({
    tableName: "test"
  });
 router.post('/arts', function(req, res) {
    var test = req.body.test;
    console.log(test);
    test.query('INSERT INTO test SET  "asd"', function(err, rows) {
     console.log(test);
    });
  });
```

The problem should be in these two blocks of code.
Please ask for more information if required.

thank you

Comment: It looks like you have the route set up correctly. Did you remember to restart node after adding the code?

Comment: Also, calling "test.query(" is almost certain to fail. The "test" variable is a string, and will not have a method called "query" defined.

Comment: yes i always restart with ctrl+f5.

Comment: i have this as var test

Comment: var test = new MyAppModel({
    tableName: "test"
  });

Comment: ctrl+f5 will reload the browser, but not the running nodejs application. To do that, you'd have to kill the nodejs process and start it again.

Comment: i run it in intelliJ idea. and im certain it doenst refresh the browser :P (in my case)

Answer (score 0):

I finaly found after a lot of time the problem...

```
'INSERT INTO test SET "asd"'

Should have been:
'INSERT INTO test SET test = "asd"'
```

*facepalm*